# Is Sugou from "Sword Art Online" dead or alive?

Tags: sword-art-online

When I was watching episode 25 of *Sword Art Online* I saw that Kirito stabbed Sugou in the neck and he left him paralyzed in the hospital parking lot. Since it's snowing he might die from hypothermia or pneumonia.  Did they ever find his body?

Want an example this..

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is, he's alive. Kirito didn't stab or cut off Sugou's neck. I did a little research on SAO Fandom, it is stated that later Sugou was captured and interrogated by the police. Here's where you can read the chronology: https://swordartonline.fandom.com/wiki/Sugou_Nobuyuki